# To do list with custom rewards to task

Tags: todo

Is there a to-do list app that allows you to add rewards to tasks. And each category of rewards to be collected after you accomplish a task? Say you put a price of 2$ to achieving tasks. After you accomplish tax x, those 2$ to be accumulated.

Answer (score 2):

There is an android application that gamifies the everyday choires and has a to-do list. This is as close as something is to what you seek. At least as far as I know. Check it out : Habitica